# Is there a notation for the group of dilations, as related to the conformal group?

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, lie-algebras, fiber-bundles, principal-bundles

I am interested in defining a connection on a principle G bundle, where G is the conformal group of orthogonal transformations and dilations.  I have not found a good way of talking about this, because many times the conformal group refers to orthogonal transformations, dilations and translations and special conformal transformations, where I only want the first two.  Is there a standard notation for the group of dilations, and for the conformal group that I am referring to?

Comment: I found the notation $CO(n)=\mathbb{R}^+\otimes SO(n)$ in this paper https://eudml.org/doc/82173, which is what I think I was looking for (near the bottom of page 44).